# Encoding issue behind cutting and pasting text as input into an application

Tags: php, encoding

I understand that when text is stored in a database it is encoded. When you type it into a text editor and hit save, it is encoded. When I type it into some source code, it is encoded.  But what really is happening when you copy and past a text from a file and place it in for example, the input text field of  a php application?  Are you here asking the application to get this text (presently not encoded), process the string and encode with the chosen encoding setting of the application?

Answer (score 0):

The accept-charset attribute specifies the character encodings that are to be used for the form submission.

The default value is the reserved string "UNKNOWN" (indicates that the encoding equals the encoding of the document containing the  element).

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8"></form>
```

Comment: when you download and parse an xml file and extract the contents of the tags that you are interested in, are these strings presently encoded?, or is it the case that they they are not encoded but will become encoded once i save the contents of the tags into my database?

Comment: Please, take a look at this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php)